# What does the "data-unsp-sanitized" attribute means?

Tags: html

I was checking a navbar markup example to use in a website, when I found the attribute "data-unsp-sanitized" placed in HTML anchor tags like this:

```
<a href="#" data-unsp-sanitized="clean">
```

I searched over Stack Overflow and Google, and surprisingly ended with no explanations of what this attribute does or why it is there.

Comment: It's not part of any standard I know of. Probably some kind of security software that scans anchor tags, ensuring they are safe to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means your anchor tag has been assigned additional information `clean`. It may be used by CSS or Javascript. More about HTML `data-*` attributes you can [read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).

Comment: I think the OP means that specific `data-` attribute, not what `data-` attributes are in general.

Comment: This is the best answer he can get.